# Programmatically change paragraph placement in Word range

Tags: vba, ms-word

I seem to be stuck with a rather simplistic problem when writing a macro for MS Word, I even feel quite embarassed for myself.
I have a range of paragraphs (content don't matter here) that need to be sorted by a given criteria (sorting is not the case here as well) - p1-p2-p3

After sorting let's say we'll have p2-p1-p3

I seem not to be able to code the very process of paragraphs exchanging places e.g.
The usual approach for variables does not really apply to Word's objects.
I'm not really looking for a code sample (but will look into ofc), but for a hint of what to approach to use. Thanks

Comment: See here, for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68923125/how-to-reverse-paragraphs-with-interop-word/68923795#68923795

Comment: Thanks, I'll have a look